# Agregar estilos a un email enviado desde php

Tags: php, css, email

me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para agregarle estilos a los datos enviados desde php, este es mi código pero no funciona, aparece todo como si fuera string en el correo:

```
$mensaje = "
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <meta charset='UTF-8'>
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p style='font-size: 20px;'>Punto de Partida: " . $punto_partida . "</p>
            <p>Destino: " . $destino . "</p>
            <p>Fecha de inicio: " . $fecha_inicio . "</p>
            <p>Hora de inicio: " . $hora_inicio . "</p>
            <p>Nombre: " . $nombre . "</p>
            <p>Teléfono: " . $telefono . "</p>
            <p>Correo: " . $correo . "</p>
        </body>
        </html>";
```

Esto es lo que aparece en el correo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang='en'>
                    <head>
                            <meta charset='UTF-8'>
                            <title>Document</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                            <p style='font-size: 20px;'>Punto de Partida: Ejemplo punto  partida</p>
                            <p>Destino: ejemplo destino</p>
                            <p>Fecha de inicio: 2018-11-15</p>
                            <p>Hora de inicio: 01:00</p>
                            <p>Nombre: Ejemplo</p>
                            <p>Teléfono: 46512231456</p>
                            <p>Correo: ejemplo@gmail.com</p>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Comment: y si posteas la libreria o el metodo que utilizas para el envio de correo seria exelente!

Comment: @Bryro no utilizo ninguna librería

Comment: En mi respuesta puse el código completo

Answer (score 0):

Me funcionó agregando la siguiente línea:

```
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Esa línea la pongo aquí:

```
$cabeceras = "From: ejemplo@gmail.com" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: ejemplo@gmail.com" . "\r\n" .
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

El código quedaría así:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST["valor"])) {
    $variable = $_POST["valor"];
    $variable = $_POST["valor"];
    $variable = $_POST["valor"];
    $variable = $_POST["valor"];
    $variable = $_POST["valor"];
    $variable = $_POST["valor"];
    $variable = $_POST["valor"];

    $para = "ejemplo@gmail.com";
    $titulo = "Titulo";
    $mensaje = "
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <meta charset='UTF-8'>
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p style='font-size: 20px;'>Texto: " . $variable . "</p>
            <p>Texto: " . $variable . "</p>
            <p>Texto: " . $variable . "</p>
            <p>Texto: " . $variable . "</p>
            <p>Texto: " . $variable . "</p>
            <p>Texto: " . $variable . "</p>
            <p>Texto: " . $variable . "</p>
        </body>
        </html>";
    $cabeceras = "From: ejemplo2@gmail.com" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: ejemplo2@gmail.com" . "\r\n" .
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
}
```

?>

Answer (score -2):

la forma en como lo tienes es igual a como lo hago yo y siempre me ha funcionado, lo unico que veo diferente en tu implementacion es la inclusion del DOCTYPE
intenta quitando la linea de DOCTYPE a ver.
ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No sabemos que libreeia utliza para el envio de correo y si es la propia de php seria agregar el content header ejemplo: $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"; no es solo poner html y enviarlo :v

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que hace el código que muestras

Comment: No utilizo ninguna librería

Comment: Es puro php, la función mail

Comment: disculpa es que no pegue bien el codigo que queria mostrar ya lo edite, yo cree una funcion que me hace el template del correo es igual a lo que mostrastes en tu pregunta y funciona bien